# Login in both Chrome extension and Webapp via Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication

**Chrome Extension part**

I have implemented a chrome extension based on Firebase.
We started the login flow by:

```
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow
```

and then after the flow is done, it will trigger the auth change listener

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(....);
```

and after that I can have the user's access token.

**WebApp part**

Now I am building a webapp using the same Firebase project. But the Firebase SDK in the webapp cannot auto login (need to login again).

**My Question**

How can I sync the auth status across both webapp and the Chrome extension

Comment: I don't think there is a way to synchronize auth state between a Chrome extension and a regular web page. They're essentially two completely separate apps, so you'll need to authenticate to both separately.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you for you comment. Then how can other Chrome extensions like the Evernote Web Clipper achieve this? I login via the Evernote extension and that action also log me in to their web app.

Comment: Ah... so it is possible after all then. They may be sharing the tokens, but I have no experience with that (hence leaving a comment and not an answer). Hopefully somebody else will know.

Comment: Currently that is not supported. You will have to implement a bridge mechanism to send messages between the chrome extension and the web page. The user would remain centralized in the extension and onAuthStateChanged listener when triggered will pass the id token to the webpage. The webpage could ask the chrome extension for the current token if the user is logged in. You could also write wrappers on the webpage to call the underlying firebase methods in the extension.

Comment: @bojeil Yes, I have sent the access token from the Chrome extension to the webapp, but I dont find a Firebase auth function allow me login a user with token (we have used both Google provider and Password provider)

Comment: You don't really need to login the user in the webapp. The user is already logged in in the chrome extension. You have to communicate with the extension every time you need to run an auth operation. Granted it is more work. If you happen to have your own backend server. You can login the user in the chrome extension, pass the id token to your backend, mint a custom token using the recently release admin sdk for the same user and pass it to your web app. You can then login using signInWithCustomToken. This require a lot of effort but there are few better options currently.

Comment: thank you, the custom token way sounds promising, I will try it